# Google App Engine: Extracting data from datastore and displaying it on a webpage

Tags: python, google-app-engine

I'm building a web application using Python as my backend language with Google App Engine. In the code below, I'm trying to extract data from my 'Survey' database, and trying to display it on the 'perma.html' web page. However, I get a blank document instead of the required data information on that page. Here's the source code of my application:

main.py

```
import os
import webapp2
import jinja2
from google.appengine.ext import db
from random import randint

template_dir = os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__), 'templates')
jinja_env = jinja2.Environment(loader = jinja2.FileSystemLoader(template_dir), autoescape=True)

class Handler(webapp2.RequestHandler):
    def write(self, *a, **kw):
        self.response.out.write(*a, **kw)
    def render_str(self, template, **params):
        t = jinja_env.get_template(template)
        return t.render(params)
    def render(self, template, **kw):
        self.write(self.render_str(template, **kw))

#databases

class Survey(db.Model):
    vam_id = db.StringProperty()
    subject = db.StringProperty(required = True)
    description = db.TextProperty(required = True)
    created = db.DateTimeProperty(auto_now_add = True)
    q1 = db.TextProperty(required = True)
    o11 = db.TextProperty(required = True)
    o12 = db.TextProperty(required = True)
    o13 = db.TextProperty(required = True)
    q2 = db.TextProperty(required = True)
    o21 = db.TextProperty(required = True)
    o22 = db.TextProperty(required = True)
    o23 = db.TextProperty(required = True)
    q3 = db.TextProperty(required = True)
    o31 = db.TextProperty(required = True)
    o32 = db.TextProperty(required = True)
    o33 = db.TextProperty(required = True)
    q4 = db.TextProperty(required = True)
    o41 = db.TextProperty(required = True)
    o42 = db.TextProperty(required = True)
    o43 = db.TextProperty(required = True) 
    q5 = db.TextProperty(required = True)
    o51 = db.TextProperty(required = True)
    o52 = db.TextProperty(required = True)
    o53 = db.TextProperty(required = True)

"""a = Survey(vam_id = "01", subject = "Metro", description = "A survey on Mumbai Metro",
            q1 = "How do you find rates fixed for Metros?", 
            o11 = "Appropriate", o12 = "Somewhat appropriate", o13 = "Inappropriate",
            q2 = "How satisfied are you with the customer service",
            o21 = "Extremely satisfied", o22 = "Moderately satisfied", o23 = "Not satisfied",
            q3 = "How satisfied are you with the interior of Mumbai Metro?",
            o31 = "Extremely satisfied", o32 = "Moderately satisfied", o33 = "Not satisfied",
            q4 = "Do you think travelling by Metro is more convenient than other transport?",
            o41 = "Yes", o42 = "No", o43 = "Can't say",
            q5 = "How will you rate Mumbai Metro?",
            o51 = "Very good", o52 = "Good", o53 = "Bad")  

a.put()         """  

class MainPage(Handler):
    def get(self):
        self.render("homepage.html")

class NewSurvey(Handler):
    def get(self):
        self.render("newsurvey.html")
    def post(self):
        vam_id = str(randint(1, 500))
        subject = self.request.get("title")
        description = self.request.get("description")
        q1 = self.request.get("q1")
        o11 = self.request.get("o11")
        o12 = self.request.get("o12")
        o13 = self.request.get("o13")
        q2 = self.request.get("q2")
        o21 = self.request.get("o21")
        o22 = self.request.get("o22")
        o23 = self.request.get("o23")
        q3 = self.request.get("q3")
        o31 = self.request.get("o31")
        o32 = self.request.get("o32")
        o33 = self.request.get("o33")
        q4 = self.request.get("q4")
        o41 = self.request.get("o41")
        o42 = self.request.get("o42")
        o43 = self.request.get("o43") 
        q5 = self.request.get("q5")
        o51 = self.request.get("o51")
        o52 = self.request.get("o52")
        o53 = self.request.get("o53")

        a = Survey(vam_id = vam_id, subject = subject, description = description, q1 = q1,
                    o11 = o11, o12 = o12, o13 = o13, q2 = q2,
                    o21 = o21, o22 = o22, o23 = o23, q3 = q3,
                    o31 = o31, o32 = o32, o33 = o33, q4 = q4,
                    o41 = o41, o42 = o42, o43 = o43, q5 = q5,
                    o51 = o51, o52 = o52, o53 = o53)
        a.put()            

class Existing(Handler):
    def get(self):
        surveys = Survey.all()
        self.render("existingsurvey.html", surveys = surveys)

class PermaSurvey(Handler):
    def get(self):
        vam = self.request.get("vam_id")
        su = Survey.all().filter("vam_id =", vam).get()
        self.render("perma.html", su = su)

app = webapp2.WSGIApplication([('/', MainPage),
                               ('/new', NewSurvey),
                               ('/existing', Existing),
                               ('/perma', PermaSurvey)], debug=True)
```

existingsurvey.html

```
<html>
<head>
    <title>Existing surveys</title>
</head>
<body>
    {% block content %}
        {% for s in surveys %}
            <a href = "/perma?vam_id = {{s.vam_id}}">{{s.subject}}</a> <br>
            {{s.description}}
            <br><br><br><br>
        {% endfor %}
    {% endblock %}
</body>
</html>
```

perma.html

```
<html>
<head>
    <title>Perma Survey</title>
</head>
<body>
{% block content %}

    <h1>{{su.subject}}</h1>



{% endblock %}   
</body>
</html>
```

Basically, I extract the 'vam_id' value from my entry of the database by passing it as a parameter in my existingsurvey.html code. Thereafter, I use that value in my 'PermaSurvey' handler in order to filter the particular entry from my datastore. But when I pass the 'su' object in the 'perma.html' web page, I am not able to display the contents of my datastore entry. Instead, I get a blank document. What's happening ?

Comment: Since you are apparently able to output datastore data to create the existingsurvey page, your problem does not appear to be with the datastore. Have you confirmed that the parameter is actually being passed correctly to the perma page? What do you see if you log `vam_id` there? The spaces in URL you create in existingsurvey.html seem suspect.

Comment: @DanielRoseman I do see the correct vam_id values being passed in the URL when I go to the perma.html page.

Comment: OK, what do you see when you log `su` before passing it to `render`?

Comment: @DanielRoseman Didn't quite understood your question. Can you elaborate?

Comment: You just said you logged "vam_id" and it was correct, I wondered what you see when you log "su".

Comment: @DanielRoseman what I meant was that I get the following URL when I reach the perma.html page: http://localhost:16080/perma?vam_id=01

Comment: Well, which kind of proves my point about the spaces, since "%20=%2001" is not going to be recognized. *Inside the function*, log the value of vam_id: I expect it will be none.

Comment: log all the things. logging.info ('variable X was: {0}'.format(X)) https://developers.google.com/appengine/articles/logging